# create XML file on other server's disk with xp_cmdshell on same network

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have two servers on my network, one for RDBMS (Sql Server 2005) and the second is Web Server (which runs IIS 7.5).

RDBMS server's local IP is **192.168.1.5** and UNC name is **DataOne**

Web Server's local IP is **192.168.1.4** and UNC name is **FirmWebOne**

With following block i can run a query and create a xml file on C: for the RDBMS server machine.
It works fine.

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SQLCmd   VARCHAR(500)

SELECT  @FileName = N'\\192.168.1.5\c$\trial_1.xml'

SELECT  @SQLCmd = 'bcp ' +
 '"SELECT I.code,L.name  ' +

' FROM Portal.dbo.inventory I LEFT JOIN Portal.dbo.inventoryLocalization L ON I.code = L.code AND L.language =''en'' ' +

' FOR XML PATH(''Product''), ROOT(''Products''), TYPE "' +

' queryout '  + @FileName +
' -w -T -S' + @@ServerName

SELECT @SQLCmd AS 'Command to execute'

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

Can i create that xml file on Web Server disk ?

I have tired Web Server's IP as  N'\192.168.1.4\c$\trial_1.xml'

and web server's UNC address as  N'\FirmWebOne\c$\trial_1.xml'

but it returns following errors.

SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance...

PS:by the way, i have checked the account with EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'
it returns  **nt authority\system** and this account have permissions on the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NT Authority\System** is a local user and I guess you didn't explicitly give permissions to him on **\FirmWebOne\c$**.
I would change account under which **xp_cmdshell** is running by setting [proxy account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190359.aspx). Then you can grant access to this user on **\FirmWebOne\c$**

BTW: I'd better avoid using C$ and create a share folder. It's more manageable and secure.

Comment: i use EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'FirmWebOne\SqlBulk', 'pass'
but this time i get 
"An error occurred during the execution of sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account. Possible reasons: the provided account was invalid or the '##xp_cmdshell_proxy_account##' credential could not be created. Error code: '1326'"  error.
but user name and password correct.

Comment: You have to create an account on DataOne server otherwise SQL Server won't see the account and won't create a proxy.

Comment: ok...
befor the SELECT @SQLCmd AS 'Command to execute' , i put following
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'net use T: \\FirmWebOne\here_ShareFolderNAme here_password /USER:FirmWebOne\here_AccountName /PERSISTENT:yes' .. and it is done. thanksss